# Handling Activity Stack in Android Apps

Tags: android, android-emulator

Lets say I have three Activities in my App.

1) Signup Activity
2) AccountActivate Activity
3) Main Activity

Order 1 -> 2 -> 3 (User Signs Up -> if Sign up is successful -> Enters PIN and activates account -> if activation successful -> lands in Main Activity

Now here is the problem.

Once I am in Main and the activation is complete, and I press the hardware key (BACK) on the phone or the emulator I am taken to AccountActivate Activity (2) again. I do not really want this to happen since the Account has been activated so the user should not really see this again. Is there a way I can handle this?

Thanks for all the help guys.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an activity from the history stack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1898886/removing-an-activity-from-the-history-stack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call `finish()` when you go from 2) to 3). Or you use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY.. This has been asked many times.

Comment: I am sorry about the repetition. Will do that, Thanks!

Comment: Hi EboMike would you be able to help me out with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036494/how-can-i-integrate-paypal-to-payout-users-when-a-button-is-clicked

Comment: Sorry, I've never used PayPal in an app, other than linking to a PayPal button in an HTML document...